# process system not working

Tags: boot, reboot, processes

Phone is not starting at all. From the last few days it was showing `LOW space` notification as usual it does when the memory is low. But this time the phone is simply not responding. What will be the solution for the same. How can I enter into my phone to free up some memory space?

I have tried rebooting it several times.Also,  tried hard reset but hard reset screen is not showing up.

Phone Model -Micromax Canvas A116.

Comment: So, is the now accessible I mean is it switch one currently ?? If yes you can try clear some space by clearing the logcat file. To do that tap *#9900# over the dailer and select the option delete dumpstat/logcat file and see if this frees some of your space ! Also, if possible I would also advise you to install junk file cleaner apps to clear the junk files stored over your device as it will also help you in extracting free space out of your device !

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the device to your computer and cut and pasting all your pictures and vidoes to your computer.